# How to install bitcoin wallet on ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, bitcoin

I would like to create a simple application that will use bitcoin. How do I install bitcoin wallet on ubuntu server?

I tried the command

```
sudo apt-get install bitcoind
```

But I get the following message:

```
~$ bitcoind

bitcoin is very out of date and has been removed.
Please see upstream sources at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/
or the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin
```

Answer (score 3):

To install Bitcoind type the following commands in Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can either get a statically linked binary from https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/ or use one of the package managers:

- https://snapcraft.io/bitcoin-core
- https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.bitcoincore.bitcoin-qt